# javascript onbeforeunload fire get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute ajax function onbeforeunload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701734/how-to-execute-ajax-function-onbeforeunload)
>   [How to capture browser close event and make a request to web service method on that event through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530259/how-to-capture-browser-close-event-and-make-a-request-to-web-service-method-on-t)

So right now this is what my onbeforeunload looks like

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var message = "Don't close me!",
  e = e || window.event;
  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = message;
  }
  // For Safari
  return message;
};
```

So this is what I'm attempting to do, this function fires and gives them a prompt to choose whether or not to navigate away from the page.  If and only if they decide to navigate away I need to fire a GET request to close out the database records.

From testing if I set up like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = $.get("url_here")
```

This was an easy fix however now I can't get the prompt and the window closes without warning.

I've also tried adding a function with a confirm to do it however it doesn't seem to work correctly.  E.G.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
  if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
    $.get("url_here");

    return true;
  }
}
```

This one gets weirder, however in most cases it just causes a message to pop up with the literal text ("true") with a yes/no prompt.

Comment: You cannot reliably do this.

Comment: +1 SLaks. There will probably be answers pointing how to do it, they just don't always work. You have to do otherwise, for example save data as the user changes them.

Comment: async false works as long as the request makes it to the server in the first second or so

Comment: have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/3kvAC/241/ and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063522/jquery-beforeunload

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/3kvAC/241 and this [Dialog box runs for 1 sec and disappears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063522/jquery-beforeunload) and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907(v=vs.85).aspx

it looks like this:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});

$(window).unload(function(){
  alert('Bye.');
});
```