# Capture the result of window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a scenario, I have to save the changes when user clicks yes on `window.onbeforeunload` for that I need to submit the form and nothing should be happen when selected no.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried this:

```
window.onbeforeunload= function(){
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?");
    if (r == true) {
        readForm.action = '/SREPS/read.do' ;
        readForm.submit();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

It did not worked 100% when ever we hit Cancel during `window.confirm` another dialog appears saying that message from web page false asking for confirmation leave this page and stay on this page. In this case if the user selects leave this page. I am not able to submit the form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture browser close event and make a request to web service method on that event through javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530259/how-to-capture-browser-close-event-and-make-a-request-to-web-service-method-on-t)

Comment: I have posted my answer below

Comment: @Harish: Don't post it as an answer if it does not answer/solve the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *cannot* use your own dialog in `onbeforeunload`.  The only thing you can do is return a string to be displayed (on some browsers).  You cannot stop the browser from leaving, only the user can control that.

What you can do is the following:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?';
};
```

This will ask the user if they want to leave or not.  Then you can use the `onunload` event to run a function when they leave.  From there, you can make a "synchronous" AJAX request to submit the form.

```
window.onunload = function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/SREPS/read.do', false);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    request.send(new FormData(readForm));
};
```

If you are using jQuery, you can do:

```
window.onunload = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/SREPS/read.do',
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        data: $(readForm).serialize()
    });
};
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying the FormData is undefined.

Comment: @Harish: Then you're probably using an older browser.  Then you'd just need to serialize the form on your own and send the data.

Comment: @Harish: What browser are you using?

Comment: This code only works with "modern" browsers.  So IE 10+.  Are you using jQuery on your page?

Comment: Yes, I am using JQuery as well.

Comment: @Harish: Then try the new code I added to my answer.