# Run Javascript function only if 'beforeunload' function returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to execute javascript function if user click "not leave" in beforeunload alert?

I use JQuery and the following code:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function (e) {
    if (formSubmitting || !isDirty()) {
        return undefined;
    }
    var confirmationMessage = 'You have unsaved work.';
    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
    return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
});
```

So how to check, if user stays on the page or leave it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522652/capture-the-result-of-window-onbeforeunload

Comment: your function doesn't make sense, just returning any value (except `undefined`) results in the same outcome, i.e. a default alert dialog like "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." is shown.

Comment: Simon Hänisch I edited it. I wanted to simplify it and did not realize this outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `beforeunload` confirmation dialog is shown to the user, there are two possibilities:

- User leaves the page: in this case `unload` event is fired.
- User stays on page: nothing will happen.

So, *leaving* can be detected by `unload` event, however *staying* cannot be detected by an event.